# Register a website as webapp in store.office.com

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service

I have a website which is made in PHP. I have implemented Azure AD Oauth2 to logging to my website as this document says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code
And it works perfectly. The user is able to login using any microsoft credentials including office 365 and live accounts.

Now, in this page(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/connect-your-app-to-o365-app-launcher) it says,
From sign-on to launcher: user experience

1.The user selects a link on the provider’s website to sign on with Office 365 credentials.
2.Azure AD presents a sign-on page with the app name and request for specific resources (profile, contacts, etc.). User consents by choosing OK.
3.Provider initiates session with the user, requesting and receiving information (terms of service agreement, confirmation of email address, etc.).
4.User is now signed in to provider’s app. The user can now find the app on the My apps page, and pin it to the launcher.

Everything works except 4. I can not find anything new in "My Apps" page. Displaying my website in office store in the "My App" section is my requirement.

My questions are,
1. Do I need to register my website as a web app to store.office.com using sellerdashboard.microsoft.com to acheive this?
2. Is it possible to register a website as webapp in store.office.com? (My website is not hosted in azure. I do have developer account. When I tried to push something to store, it asks for package which I dont have because what I have is a website not app.)

- Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have an premium account for this. I have also just been working with this and got the same "missing option"

Comment: I think developer account should be enough to publish anything to store. But store accepts only packages.